# How to check no. of return values from a function

Tags: python

I know that in python you can return multiple values simply by doing

```
return a,b,c
```

and the caller get a tuple of these values. In that case you can simply check the length of the tuple to know how many values were returned.

```
ret = f()
len(ret)
```

However, when a single value is returned, this wrapping doesn't happen, and you directly get the returned value.

In that case, trying to call `len` will raise `TypeError` if the returned value doesn't have a length, or if it does, (like if an array of length 10 was returned) you'll draw the wrong conclusion - a single array of length 10 was returned, not 10 individual values.

So my question is: what's the best way to handle these edge cases? And more, is it even possible to distinguish these two:

```
def f():
    return 1,2,3

def f():
    ret = (1,2,3)
    return ret
```

Comment: What do you mean, distinguish them? They return *exactly* the same thing, that is a single tuple of three values.

Comment: When I face this situation, normally I use `isinstance` to test if the returned variable type is a list or tuple. It works to me.

Comment: you don't actually try to "distinguish" the return value, but HOW it was visually composed. Edit your question if that's so

Comment: @DanielRoseman So 1,2,3 and (1,2,3) are the same? The parentheses are just syntactic sugar?

Comment: as I mentioned previousely ... it's only about visual composition

Comment: Yes @hoodakaushal try typing `x = 1, 2, 3` and then `type(x)` on a Python console.

Comment: But sometimes you may wanna return a number or a list. For this case I suggested the `isinstance`.